# PHP to Javascript compare string with characters list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this PHP function to compare a username `$value` with a characters list:

```
strlen($value) == count(array_intersect(array_map("strtoupper", str_split($value)), str_split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_-")))
```

I need to obtain something similar using Jquery. I have problems with `array_intersect()` at the moment, I can't find any similar function.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what the right side of the expression does? (Or what you are trying to compare in general?)

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#intersection

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 It explodes `$value` into an array, then intersects it with the caracters list and count the occurrencies (they must be same as `$value` length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow has already [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885557/240613) about array intersection in JavaScript.

You may also be interested by [intersection function in Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection).

Finally, wouldn't it be easier here to use regular expressions? In PHP, your code becomes as simple as:

```
$isValidUserName = preg_match('/^[A-Z_\-]+$/i', $value);
```

In JavaScript:

```
var isValidUserName = (/^[A-Z_\-]*$/i).test('Hello_World');
```

Comment: Thanks, it's much more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and try:

```
_.intersection(A, B);
```

Look into [`_.intersection()`](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection)